# does weblogic 11g ( 10.3.6 ) support jdk 1.8 - issue while connecting to db2

Tags: db2, java-8, weblogic-10.x

we were earlier using java 1.6 with weblogic 10.3.6 ( 11g ) and were connecting to db2 just fine.
we had used Oracles db2driver Type 4 for the same.

Now we need to use IBM JDK 1.8 and when I do this the same datasource that was working earlier fails.
The reason is - it seems with JDK 1.8 - the class - sun.io.CharToByteConverter is missing while it was present in 1.6.

So doing a search in SO - found a similar issue reported:
[Connect to DB2 database in eclipse via jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801841/connect-to-db2-database-in-eclipse-via-jdbc)
so we downloaded the driver - db2jcc4.jar from IBM website.
However we get issues in the datasource setup screen - on choosing this datasource:
[image]

On this screen - dont see an option to select database host
[image]
so do I have to use Oracle's jars only ?
Thanks
satish

Comment: Try upgrading the JARs to match your JDK version.  All dependencies need to be satisfied correctly as well.

Comment: @duffymo - thanks can you elaborate on what I should look for ?